# Class or Enum to restrict function parameter to list of valid values c#

Tags: c#, class, enums

Let's say I have something like:
Vehicles.
Below Vehicles I have Cars, Trucks and Pickups.
Below Cars I only have BMW and Toyota.

Now I want to call something like:

```
if (NumberOfSeats(Vehicles.Cars.Toyota) {}
```

So NumberOfSeats should be restricted to only receive BMW and Toyota:

```
public int NumberOfSeats(??) { return 4;}
```

But it should give a compile time error if I call:

```
if (NumberOfSeats(Vehicles.Cars.Yamaha) {}
```

Furthermore I would like to have a method to BMW, that will return a string value (let'say `Name()`)

Should my class composition be looking at Enums, Classes, Inheritance or combination?

Comment: Would putting `NumberOfSeats` as a virtual property of the `Vehicle` object solve your problem?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve. I think you need a abstract base class `Vehicle` with method `NumberOfSeats`. If this is the design question -- [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) will be a better place.

Comment: This looks like a design smell, and also like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try to describe what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This isn't really something that enums are designed to be used for, I agree with Sriram that you are much better just creating a method (or property) that can be overridden

Comment: Tx, the real point I want to get to is to have a fixed list of names of cars (not instances of an object) and I want to pass this fixed name to a method.  So NumberOfSeats is not a property in this case (although the real world object it will make sense).  Maybe I will have to rethink the wording of the question a little.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are thinking in backwards. My way of thinking is to create analogy between real-world objects and software classes (This is my way oıf Object Oriented thinking).

When I consider a real-world scenario there is no such thing as "number of seats" in the world itself. It is a property of a vehicle. Cars have this property buses have this property, Cars usually have 4 (or 5) seats, buses have 45 etc.

So I would implement it as a property of a vehicle ot a self method. This way it will be more meaningful. Such as:

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    int NumberOfSeats { get; }
    string Brand { get; set; }
}

public class Car : IVehicle
{
    public int NumberOfSeats { get; private set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    public Car(int noofseats, string brand)
    {
        this.NumberOfSeats = noofseats;
        this.Brand = brand;
    }
}

Car bmw = new Car(4, "BMW");
Car toyota = new Car(4, "Toyota");
Car qashqai = new Var(7, "Nissan");
```